# Auto-send mail after uploading an attachment in Gmail

Tags: gmail

I'm using Gmail to send attachments to Amazon with its auto-converting service to send ebooks to my Kindle.

Uploading the big document attachments can really be a waste of time. I have to wait for that and click "send" when the upload is complete.

Is there a way that Gmail can auto-send the mail once the uploading is finished, so that I can do something else in the meantime?

Comment: Can you not immediately hit send, so that the message goes when the upload finishes?

Comment: Everett is right. I always click send once the upload starts and the mail is sent on upload completion.

Answer (score 1):

A new Labs feature, [Background Send](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2011/04/new-in-labs-background-send.html), let's you go about working in Gmail (reading other messages, etc.) without waiting for a file to finish uploading.

Answer (score 0):

Just click "Send".

Gmail will send the email after the upload is completed.

Answer (score -1):

Try configuring your Outlook for GMail, then open a new mail in Outlook. Add attachments, and send immediately. This won't stop from composing a new mail.

For Configuring GMail on Outlook, You can check this URL. [How To Geek](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/17248/set-up-gmail-imap-in-outlook-2010/)